# Python script to upload a file to a remote server

Tags: python, upload, sftp, pysftp

I am working on a project that requires us to upload a vile via SFTP to a remote server, and we are having troubles doing this.  We tried following this [youtube guide](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TTks9B4PMKU), but we are having some issues.

We are getting a "no such file" error when we run the script, and we know for sure that the file exists and that we have given the python script the right name and location for the file.

This is the script as we have it right now:

```
import pysftp as sftp

def sftpTry():
       try:
            s = sftp.Connection(host='babbage.cs.missouri.edu', username ='<username>', password = '<password>')

            remotepath = '~it3001s14grp1/videos/newVideo/new.avi'
            #localpath = '/etc/motion/capture/hello.txt'
            localpath = '/etc/motion/capture/06--2014-05-15---16-16-25.avi'
            s.put(localpath, remotepath)

            s.close()

    except Exception, e:
            print str(e)

sftpTry();
```

Answer (score 1):

You should begin your remote path with a forward slash "/". Also, check the directory you are specifying in the remotepath. You should try to do a `pwd` in the directory when you login into the server (say using ssh). The remote-path should be specified exactly like that.

Although you do have the filename name in the remote path, it would throw an error if you specify just the folder's name.

Another tip would be to use `getpass` instead of hard-coding the password:

```
passwd = getpass.getpass()
s = sftp.Connection(host='<host>', username = '<username>', password = passwd)
```

Comment: ^ you should create public and private keys using ssh-key-gen instead of using a password